# XML Unmarshalling attribute differently in case of arrays in Golang

Tags: xml, go, unmarshalling

I have a web service where I expect to receive two different requests; one is called `Request` containing just one `Request` and the other is called `RequestBulk` which contains an array of `Request`s. Both mapped to Golang structs as follows:

```
type RequestBulk struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name  `xml:"https://item.com RequestBulk"`
    Message  string    `xml:"Message"`
    Request  []Request `xml:"Request,omitempty"`
}

type Request struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"https://item.com Request"`
    Text    string   `xml:"text"`
}
```

Unmarshalling the following XMLs works as expected:

```
<Request xmlns="https://item.com">
  <text>Some request text</text>
</Request>
```

```
<RequestBulk xmlns="https://item.com">
  <Message>Some Text</Message>
  <Request xmlns="https://item.com">
    <text>Some request text</text>
  </Request>
  <Request xmlns="https://item.com">
    <text>Some other request text</text>
  </Request>
</RequestBulk>
```

#### The Problem

In `RequestBulk`, if I change

```
Request []Request `xml:"Request,omitempty"`
```

to

```
RequestMessage []Request `xml:"RequestMessage,omitempty"`
```

and change the XML to:

```
<RequestBulk xmlns="https://item.com">
  <Message>Some Text</Message>
  <RequestMessage xmlns="https://item.com">
    <text>Some request text</text>
  </RequestMessage>
  <RequestMessage xmlns="https://item.com">
    <text>Some other request text</text>
  </RequestMessage>
</RequestBulk>
```

I get the following error:

> expected element type <Request> but have <RequestMessage>

Obviously because of the `` XMLName xml.Name `xml:"https://item.com Request"` ``

#### The Question

How do I keep the `Request` struct unchanged and still accept messages of type `RequestBulk` with a different name for the struct `Request`, namely, `RequestMessage`?

In other words; How do I use the same struct with different namespaces?

---

Run it on [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/WjFSnp7byo_c).

Comment: Your request type includes `XMLName` specifying the tag name is `Request`. If that's not what you want, remove it.

Comment: @Adrian I am aware of this and I have also mentioned it in the post. The question starts with precisely the opposite of what you suggested. Please read the question again!

Comment: I did, but you accepted an answer that modifies the `Request` type by adding a new method to it, so keeping `Request` unchanged doesn't seem to be a hard requirement.

Comment: @Adrian yes, it modifies the `Request` but only in the case if the name is `RequestMessage`. As mentioned at the beginning of my question, I want to be able to handle both cases. Receiving requests with the name `Request` or `RequestMessage`. Are you aware of a better way to do that?

Comment: You can handle both cases either way. You don't need the `XMLName` for the single `Request` use case: https://play.golang.org/p/D1P1bVDADe7

Comment: This would work for `xml.Unmarshal` but not for `xml.Marshal` because the namespace would be missing.

Comment: @Adrian anything to add other than voting down the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the `Unmarshaler` interface to overwrite the element's local name before passing the element on to the decoder for the actual unmarshaling.

```
func (r *Request) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    if start.Name.Local == "RequestMessage" {
        start.Name.Local = "Request" // overwrite
    }
    type tmp Request // avoid infinite recursive calls to Request.UnmarshalXML
    return d.DecodeElement((*tmp)(r), &start) // unmarshal
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/0a_gpgkywwf